# VB.Net I cannot change my target framework

Tags: vb.net, .net-framework-version

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and programming language is Vb.net. I already installed Net Framework version 4 but I cannot see it from the list below? Can someone tell me why?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: VS 2008 only supported NET 3.5 and lower.  You need at least VS2010 for Net 4.0

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Plutonix's comment as an answer here:

> VS 2008 only supported NET 3.5 and lower. You need at least VS2010 for Net 4.0